# Wordpress gallery remove <br />

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image-gallery

just realized that by default gallery post type has `<br style="clear: both">` tags in the code after every three pictures(every 3, because I selected 3 columns of pics in gallery options).

What and where should I modify or add to my theme code to prevent these tags from being pushed to my gallery posts as this destroys responsive layout for tablets.

Maybe adding some php to my functions file.

I tried to use css on `<br />` tags under gallery posts to display: none. This solves part of issue - removes line breaks, but still messes up my css applied on nth-child(2n).

Any suggestions or links would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector, that should do it.

```
.gallery-item:nth-of-type(2n) {
    /* styles */
}
```

And yes, keep the `<br>` as hidden is a good idea.

```
.gallery br {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1st option: PHP FIX**

You can do something on functions.php file in your theme folder to be sure to remove the 
 tags or its instances throughout the image gallery.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_br_gallery', 11, 2);
function remove_br_gallery($output) {
    return preg_replace('/<br style=(.*)>/mi', '', $output);
}
```

**Or as a 2nd option: CSS FIX**

style.css in your theme folder add:

```
.gallery br {
    display:none;
}

.gallery:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: &quot; &quot;;
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Preg replace should contains apostrophes.

```
return preg_replace('/<br style="(.*)">/mi','',$output);
```